# C: How to find the day name for a given day of the year input by user

Tags: c

The user inputs a day of a month and a month and then the output will give the user the day of the year. For example:

> -input: day=24, month=2
>
> -output: day=55

So my question is how do I give the day name like Wednesday, Monday, etc. for the day of the year? For example:

> -input: day=1, month=1
>
> -output: day=1, Sunday

Here's my code:

```
int countDays(int, int, int[]);

int main() {
  int daysInMonth[] = { 31, 28, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31 };
  int day, month;

  printf("enter day: ");
  scanf("%d", &day);

  printf("Enter month: ");
  scanf("%d", &month);

  printf("There are %d days \n", countDays(day, month, daysInMonth));
  return 0;
}

int countDays(int day, int month, int daysInMonth[]) {
  char *c[]={"Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday"};
  int charc[6];
  int k, j, a;
  int b = 0;
  int dayno[31][12];
  for (k = 0; k < 12; k++) {
    for (j = 0; j < daysInMonth[k]; j++) {

      dayno[j][k] = ++b;
    }
    a = dayno[day - 1][month - 1];
  }
  return a;
}
```

Comment: You need the year to do so. And if you have the year there is a formula for it; random link offered by Google: https://blog.artofmemory.com/how-to-calculate-the-day-of-the-week-4203.html

Comment: Note: `c[], int charc[6]` are not used.

Comment: I did some testing before uploading this so some part is not used for testing

Comment: @Ducuh Do you only want to find the day for the year 2017 only? Because you haven't included any code that lets a user input the year.

Comment: @frslm for now yes

Comment: Note that even to just find the numeric answer (55 in your example) you need the year as well due to leap years.

Comment: http://c-faq.com/misc/zeller.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you're currently only interested in working with the year 2017, you can easily figure out the day of the week by taking `countDays()` modulo 7. You can extend what you currently print in `main()`:

```
printf("There are %d days \n", countDays(day, month, daysInMonth));
```

With:

```
int days = countDays(day, month, daysInMonth);
char *c[] = {"Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday"};

printf("There are %d days; day of the week: %s \n", days, c[(days - 1) % 7]);
```

Answer (score 0):

> How to find the day name for a given day of the year input by user

Use `mktime()` to calculate the day of the week for a given year, month, day.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>

const char *day_name(int year, int month, int day) {
  struct tm tm = { .tm_year = year - 1900, .tm_mon = month - 1, .tm_mday = day,
      .tm_isdst = -1 };
  time_t t = mktime(&tm);
  if (t == -1) { 
    return "?";
  }
  static const char *dow[] = { "Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday",
      "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday" };
  return dow[tm.tm_wday];
}

int main(void) {
  puts(day_name(2017, 1, 1));
  puts(day_name(2017, 2, 24));
  puts(day_name(2017, 11, 14));
}
```

Output

```
Sunday
Friday
Tuesday
```

---

With OP's code use a variation on `countDays(month, day)`

```
#define Jan1_2017DOW (0 /* Sunday */) 
#define Jan1Number 1
int dow = (countDays(month, day) - Jan1Number + Jan1_2017DOW) % 7;
puts(c[dow]);
```

Answer (score 0):

here is a simple solution :)

```
void countDays(int day, int month, int daysInMonth[])
{
    char c[][15] =  {"Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday" };
    int totaldays=0;
    for(int i=0;i<month-1;i++)
    {
        totaldays+= daysInMonth[i];
    }

    totaldays += day;

    printf("There are %d days \n", totaldays);

    printf("\n day : %s",c[(totaldays-1)%7]);

    return;
}
```

after a little changes to your code with your own approach :)

Comment: practically both are same.. but it is confusing.. thanks for suggestion :)

Comment: @Ducuh , You need not to use a 2d array in the procedure, hence, this would be a simple solution here. try out :)

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>

char *WEEK[] =  {"Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday" };
int DAYS_IN_MONTH[] =  {31, 28, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31};

int countDays(int day, int month);
char *dayName(int day);

int main(){
    int day, month;

    printf("enter day: ");
    scanf("%d", &day);

    printf("Enter month: ");
    scanf("%d", &month);

    int days = countDays(day, month);
    if(days != -1){
        printf("There are %i days \n", days);
        printf("The day name is %s\n", dayName(days));
    }else{
        printf("Error\n");
    }

    return 0;
}

int countDays(int day, int month){
    if(day >DAYS_IN_MONTH[month-1])
        return -1;

    int num_days = 0;
    for(int i = 0;i < month-1;i++){
        num_days+=DAYS_IN_MONTH[i];
    }
    return num_days+day;

}

char *dayName(int days){
    return WEEK[(days-1) % 7];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Taken from *"Compilers: Principles, Techniques and Tools"* from Aho, Sethi and Ullman.

```
day = (1461 * year) / 4 + (153 * month + 2) / 5 + month_day;
```

(beware that `/` means integer division here, all numbers must be integers) This formula is attributed to Tanzen[1963] there. if you apply `% 7` to that formula, after applying the proper offset, you'll get the day of week.